# Can I publish a library for Android with dependecies on Android SDK as JAR?

Tags: java, android, publish, android-library

I'm publishing my first library for Android.

Most of the guides and tutorials out there show how to publish the library as `AAR`, but I came to wonder whether I need to do it this way if I don't have manifest entries, resources, etc.

My library has just two dependencies on Android SDK: `android.os.Handler` and `android.os.Looper`.

In this situation, can I publish it as `JAR`, or the moment I have dependencies on Android I must use `AAR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish your library as JAR, if you don't need to include resources or manifest.
If your library has additional dependencies (not included in Android), then specify it in POM file

Comment: But what would be the correct way of adding Handler and Looper dependencies  from android.os package so that my library can compile and be tested (I'm not using the internal implementation of either of them)?

Comment: Android is `provided` dependency in Maven. Android Gradle Plugin also adds it as `provided`.